# Cannot fire event from Button in user control contained in Extended Toolkit DropDownButton

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I've some problem while executing a button which is located inside DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate -> DropDownButton. Fyi, the button is embedded inside a user control. Code as below :

DataGrid Column Template :

```
<Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
                        <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <extToolkit:DropDownButton Width="Auto"
                                                           Height="Auto"
                                                           Content="Request"                                                              
                                                           >
                                    <extToolkit:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                                        <local:ButtonGroup />
                                    </extToolkit:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
                                </extToolkit:DropDownButton>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

View Model :

```
ButtonSetStatusEvent = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(SetStatus));

public ICommand ButtonSetStatusEvent
{
  get
  {
    return m_ButtonSetStatusEvent;
  }
  set
  {
    m_ButtonSetStatusEvent = value;
  }

}

private void SetStatus(object o)
{

  if (o.ToString() == "CmdWait")
  { 
    coStatus = (int)Status.Waiting;
    CoStatusDisplay = Status.Waiting.ToString();
  }
}
```

Button trigger XAML :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">                        
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource=    {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType=local:GridOverview,
                        AncestorLevel=1},
                        Path=DataContext.ButtonSetStatusEvent}"
                        CommandParameter="CmdWait"
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />                      

                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

So how do I make it possible to fire the click event of the button?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried using the Command property of the Button instead of using a trigger.  By default Click calls the command.

Comment: tried but no luck..but it will work if I put the user control (which containing the button) directly into DataGridRow (besides putting in to DropDownButton)

Answer (score 0):

solved by implementing ViewModelLocator